# What is wrong with this Doctrine querying on ManyToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying Symfony 4 and I can't get this query right. The same thing worked OK in Symfony 3. I have 2 entities. One is a person and the other is a day. The relation is ManyToMany. I would like to get all days for a specific person

I tried using MEMBER OF and joining tables, but nothing works for this example.

// Day entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person", inversedBy="days")
 */
private $person;
```

// Person entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Day", mappedBy="person")
 */
private $days;
```

// Repository function

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->andWhere('d.person = :person')
        ->setParameter('person', $person)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
```

This is the error I get:

> In QueryException.php line 65: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 58 near
>   'person = :pe': Error: Invalid PathExpression.
>   StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

In QueryException.php line 43:

> SELECT d FROM App\Entity\Day d WHERE d.date = :date AND d.person =
>   :person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not about Symfony version it's about orm version, i guess

So you could try this by using IDENTITY

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->andWhere('IDENTITY(d.person) = :person')
    ->setParameter('person', $person)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

or

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->leftJoin('d.person', 'p')
    ->andWhere('p.id = :person')
    ->setParameter('person', $person)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: It is this error if I try this code: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 67 near 'person) = :p': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.

Comment: Yes the second one is working. You forgot ) in andWhere part after p.id. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get person related days just from association like $person->getDays()

Comment: Yes I know, but point of this function is to get specific day for specific person. so my intent is to also add where to filter dates. $query->andWhere('d.date = :date').